# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot after new install on 480GB SSD in IdeaCentre Q180

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, boot-repair

my situation:

1. the regular SATA HDD with Ubuntu 16 in my IdeaCentre Q180 worked fine until lately. Diagnosis: hard disk failure. I decided to get a new SSD to replace the broken HDD.
2. Install with the SSD installed to the internal SATA port, BIOS Setting SATA AHCI and using a standard Ubuntu 18 ISO USB Stick works and the installation finishes with "success, please reboot system now".
3. Reboot gives me: no operating system found.

**NOW strange:** If I unplug the SSD from the internal SATA Port, take out the SSD after installation and put it into a USB (USB to SATA bridge) case and plug this into the IdeaCentre, the system boots without problems.

I used Boot-Repair with many of the available options but with no change in behavior.

Setting the BIOS SATA Mode to IDE or AHCI does not change anything. I also resorted the boot order of devices to all possible permutations - no change.

Anyone with an idea why the SSD does boot via a USB Bridge but not connected to the internal SATA connector?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that you used a Ubuntu 18 ISO USB Stick with the new SSD in a USB case.

Why not inserting the new SSD plugged into the IdeaCentre, setting the BIOS SATA Mode to  AHCI preferrably, and the running the Ubuntu 18 ISO USB Stick to install Ubuntu?

As far as I know Ubuntu sets its boot path with inclusion of the port-information as put in the BIOS such as USB01, USB02, HDD02 etcetera. So a imho possible solution is to edit the bootrecord on the SSD to include the right port information.

I am just a curious curious Ubuntu newbie, please answer me if you can.

Yours sincerely,
Stef Olling
mailto: stef.olling@gmail.com

Comment: Misunderstanding! I installed with the ssd installed to the SATA Socket, Install Media was an USB Stick. Since it did not boot, I moved (after many attempts) the ssd to an USB case and the very same SSD with no modification does boot when sitting in the USB SATA Bridge case.